# Can I wrap the node text in a WinForms TreeView

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

The ASP.NET TreeView has a NodeWrap property, is there an equivalent way of accomplishing the same thing in a WinForms TreeView?

EDIT:

Thanks for your suggestions of other controls, unfortunately my client will not permit the use of third-party controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible. You might look for a 3rd party tree view with more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a panel to put your treeview in it, although it is not exactly does the thing you want but it helps controlling consistency and control borders.