# Word wrap in TreeNode

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, alignment, treenode

When inserting a node in TreeView with long text - horizontal scrollbar appears. Is there a way to word wrap the text in TreeNode, instead of scrolling?

Currently I use solution that splits the text according to TreeView's width and display its chunks in different nodes, but the "alignment" doesn't holds after resizing and just looks weird.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is *wrap*, not *align*.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940076/can-i-wrap-the-node-text-in-a-winforms-treeview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the Scrollable property of your TreeView to false will eliminate the scrollbars, but it will also cut off your text -- probably not what you want.

This [MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/64dfd21a-120c-4d6a-81d8-efae46bc3008) give an answer that seems workable, but I don't know that you're interested in using the OwnerDrawText function to draw the nodes yourself.

Personally, I'd try to rethink the whole thing, if possible -- shorter node text, bigger tree area, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I had a similar issues, it might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.nodewrap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx .  Note its only for the web (ASP.NET).